# How to achieve the Horizontal scroll with Image and changing color dynamically?

Tags: android, colors, imageview, background-color

[image]

I want to achieve this screenshot like design with Horizontal scroll view.
I already done with the Horizontal scroll view with the help of Wheel view library 
https://github.com/chemalarrea/Android-wheel

But I am not getting any idea about how to fill a color in this images without disturbing image square area using setBackground method for Imageview.

```
      <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

                <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView
                    android:id="@+id/slotwheel_look_color"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Adapter

```
        private class SlotMachineAdapter_Look extends AbstractWheelAdapter {
    // Image size
    final int IMAGE_WIDTH = 100;
    final int IMAGE_HEIGHT = 100;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private LinearLayout mLn_parant;
    private ImageView mImg_condition;
    // Layout inflater
    private Context context;

    // Slot machine symbols
    private final int items[] = new int[]{
            R.drawable.image_1,
            R.drawable.image_2,
            R.drawable.image_3,
            R.drawable.image_4,
            R.drawable.image_5,
            R.drawable.image_6,
            R.drawable.image_7,
            R.drawable.image_8,
            R.drawable.image_9
    };

    // Cached images
    private List<SoftReference<Bitmap>> images;


    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public SlotMachineAdapter_Look(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        images = new ArrayList<SoftReference<Bitmap>>(items.length);
        for (int id : items) {
            images.add(new SoftReference<Bitmap>(loadImage(id)));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Loads image from resources
     */
    private Bitmap loadImage(int id) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), id);
        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, true);
        bitmap.recycle();
        return scaled;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemsCount() {
        return items.length;
    }

    // Layout params for image view
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);

    @Override
    public View getItem(int index, View cachedView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView img;
        if (cachedView != null) {
            img = (ImageView) cachedView;
        } else {
            img = new ImageView(context);
        }
        img.setLayoutParams(params);
        SoftReference<Bitmap> bitmapRef = images.get(index);
        Bitmap bitmap = bitmapRef.get();
        if (bitmap == null) {
            bitmap = loadImage(items[index]);
            images.set(index, new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));
        }
        BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
        img.setBackground(ob);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        img.setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW);


        return img;
```

//            return view;
        }

```
}
```

Please help me out for this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try using `setColorFilter` or `setTint` for your image? This will not disturb the image's background color.

Comment: yes setColorFilter is working but it's not giving the effect like this screen shot.and setTint is not available directly.

Comment: By "Effect like screenshot" do u mean the darkened areas and lighter areas?

Comment: yes As a result of this method flat image fill with the color return to my imageview

Comment: @KDOSHI for shadow color you have to give this as background of imageview parent. And use colorfilter for imageview.

Comment: @RahulSharma you are right about some case but did not achieve totally as expected..just getting the border using this.
I am using this  
  BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
 img.setBackgroundDrawable(ob);
  img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: is your imageview have some parent in xml?

Comment: yes Linear layout

Comment: @RahulSharma : See the updates in Question
I am using SlotMachineAdapter code and bind Imageview inside this wheelview.

Comment: @KDOSHI instead of this show me adapter layout file

Comment: @RahulSharma : I update the adapter code.
You can also suggest me another Horizontal Scrollview which can achieve this Actually it's bit difficult to NOtify the adpter and change the color in this

Comment: @KDOSHI added my answer. You have to create one xml drawable **shadow_shape.xml** for background shadow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123791/discussion-between-kdoshi-and-rahul-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

Used the `setColorFilter`

```
Drawable myIcon = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.myicon);
ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter( Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE );
myIcon.setColorFilter(filter);
Imageview.setImageDrawable(myIcon);
```

Or

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
final int newColor = res.getColor(R.color.new_color);
image.setColorFilter(newColor, Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: Not giving output same as screenshot.